# Cant switch to fullscreen mode from an iframe

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, fullscreen

I have a Backbone view with a button that should make the view goto fullscreen on click. I'm using [screenfull.js](https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js/), and I cant see any different from the examples and my code. But `console.log(screenfull.enabled);` always return `false` in the clickHandler.

```
var FullScreenButton = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({

  tagName: 'button',

  initialize: function () {
    this.$el.click(_.bind(this.goFullScreen, this));
  },

  goFullScreen: function () {
    console.log(screenfull.enabled);
    screenfull.request(this.options.container);
  }
});
```

also without screenfull.js it dont g oto fullscreen:

```
goFullScreen: function() {

  var element = document.documentElement;

  if (element.requestFullScreen) {
    element.requestFullScreen();
  } else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    element.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
    element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that the app runs in an iframe. Adding the `allowFullScreen="true"` attribute to the iframe fixes the bug.